# No Java files found that extend CordovaActivity

Tags: android, cordova, taco

I'm attempting to build a cordova app to release to android devices but receiving the following error message:

"Error: No Java files found that extend CordovaActivity"

It appears that the source of the error is that build folder that is to contain the source files is not being built. That is, the files that are to be created in the folder "src" isn't generated during the build and so the following warning is returned during each build:

ls: no such file or directory: ...\platforms\android\src\io\cordova\myappedc27c*.java

That is, the directory path "..\io\cordova\myappedc27c" is not being created.

Currently running Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7 on Windows 7 Pro.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Issue was resolved by deleting "platforms" folder and rebuilding.

Answer (score 4):

`ionic cordova platform rm android` then `ionic cordova platform add android@latest` command solved the problem for my Ionic 3 application.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me after renaming the default Cordova config and package names. I fixed it by doing the following:

```
cordova platform remove android

cordova platform add android
```

Substitute `android` for each platform you'll be using.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing an Ionic (5) app and saw this randomly pop up as well. Removing just the `android` platform under `platforms` wasn't good enough. I removed the entire `platforms` directory and while I was at it, also removed `out-tsc`, `plugins` and `www`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens most of the time when you change the `<widget id="com.xxx.appname"` in the `config.xml`

to make sure the package name in the android project is correct as per the `config.xml`

suppose your app package name in `config.xml` is as **com.mycompany.appname**

**Step 1**

Open `platforms/android/app/src/main/java` folder and find the `MainActivity.java`

`MainActivity.java` should be inside folder `com/mycompany/appname`

So the full path need to be like `platforms/android/app/src/main/com/mycompany/appname/MainActivity.java`

**Step 2**

Open `Mainactivity.java`
the first line should be same package name as below.

```
package com.mycompany.appname
```

once you corrected the issue, you can try again.

```
cordova prepare 
cordova build android
```